# Numeric sorting in Perl - wrong output

Tags: perl, sorting

I am trying to sort an array, but the output is not as expected. My array has:

```
11873
11873
11873
14361
16857
15795
14361
14361
14361
```

After I sort with following code, I get same array:

```
@sort_start= (sort{my $b <=>my $g} @start);
```

I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$a` instead of `$g`, and don't use `my` in the sort block.  Refer to [perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

```
@sort_start= sort {$b <=> $a} @start;
```

You should use `warnings`.  That would've shown you some messages.

If you want to sort in ascending order, swap `$a` and `$b`.